# Upgraded to Espresso 2.1 and now getting dependency conflict

Tags: android, android-espresso

While setting up Espresso 2.1 and the latest version of the Android Testing Support Library, I encountered the next Warning upon building:

> Confilct with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'.
>   Resolved versions for app and test app differ

My *build.gradle* file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
...
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
...
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I found an [existing issue](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=136#makechanges):

> we built against the old 22.0.0 and didn't upgrade to 22.1.0. 
>   The runner depends on com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0 which conflicts with the latest support library release (22.1.0)

I told gradle which version of support-annotations it needs to resolve to by adding the following line to my dependencies list:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.0'
```

and the warning is gone.

Answer (score 0):

@appoll [Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/build.gradle) Stephan Linzner added workaround for that.

Above I've added his comment to this issue, which explains solution:

> we are aware of the issue. The gist is that the runner depends on com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0 which conflicts with the latest support library release (22.1.0). The correct way to solve this right now, is to tell Gradle which version of support-annotations it needs to resolve to.